App Crashes on Image Picker Launch in Expo (SDK 51) for Physical Android Device, Works Fine on iOS and Android Emulator
I'm facing an issue with the Expo Image Picker (expo-image-picker version ~15.0.5) while using SDK 51. The image picker works as expected on iOS builds and the Android emulator, but crashes the app on a physical Android device when I try to select an image from the gallery.
The error occurs 99% of the time and the app crashes, but it works rarely in a few cases. I have checked that the necessary permissions are granted, and the issue still persists. Below is the code where the crash happens:
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const pickImage = async () => {
    try {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
        });
        if (result.canceled) {
            console.log("result canceled");
            return;
        }

        console.log(result?.assets[0]?.uri);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};`

{
"android": {
"permissions": [
"CAMERA",
"READ_MEDIA_IMAGES",
"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
"RECORD_AUDIO",
"POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
]
}

Error Message:
less
Copy code
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Can't stop due to wrong state(INITIALIZED)
io.reactivex.internal.observers.EmptyCompletableObserver.onError(EmptyCompletableObserver.java:51)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:74)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromAction.subscribeActual(CompletableFromAction.java:38)
io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1794)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)
io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop due to wrong state(INITIALIZED)
android.media.MediaMuxer.stop(MediaMuxer.java:492)
a.b.a(SourceFile:1)
a.b$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromAction.subscribeActual(CompletableFromAction.java:34)
io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1794)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)
io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Question:
Has anyone faced a similar issue with the Expo Image Picker on a physical Android device? Any ideas on how to resolve the crash or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.
the same happen for launch camera i doubt there is something around configuration
Ensured that the necessary permissions are granted, including READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and storage permissions.
Verified that the issue only occurs on physical Android devices, and not on the Android emulator or iOS.
tried on multiple android devices with my dev build apks but keeps crashing
Checked the expo-image-picker documentation and tried using a different configuration, but the issue persists.
expecting:it should give me image uri which i can console it without crashing the app even once as its working fine for ios and android(emulator)`
